# Interval of validity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following nonlinear ode
$$
x'(t)=t^2e^{nx^2},x(t_0)=0
$$
and i have to proof the existence and uniqueness of a solution and find the interval of validity of the maximal solution for $n\leq0$. The first part is easy since i only have to proof the Lipschitz condition and apply Picard's theorem, my problem lies with maximal solution interval, any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

To find the interval of existence of the solution, one can simply solve this equation. For this equation, it is better to do this not completely, so as not to deal with the imaginary error function. Separating the variables, we obtain
$$
\frac{dx}{dt}=t^2e^{nx^2}
$$
$$
e^{-nx^2}\,dx=t^2\,dt
$$
Taking into account the initial condition, we obtain
$$
\int_0^{x(t)}e^{-nx^2}\,dx=\int_{t_0}^tt^2\,dt
$$
$$
\int_0^{x(t)}e^{-nx^2}\,dx=\frac{t^3}3-\frac{t_0^3}3
$$
Consider the function $f(x)=\int_0^{x}e^{-nx^2}\,dx$ for $x\in[0,+\infty)$.
We know the following:

- $f(0)=0$.
- $f(x)$ is continuous.
- Since $e^{-nx^2}>0$, $f(x)$ is strictly increasing.
- Since $-n\ge 0$, $e^{-nx^2}\ge1$, thus $f(x)\ge\int_0^{x}dx=x$, thus we have $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$.

This implies that there exists an inverse function $f^{-1}:[0,+\infty)\to [0,+\infty)$. Hence, the solution $x(t)$ is defined for any $t>t_0$ and is equal to
$$
x(t)=f^{-1}\left( \frac{t^3}3-\frac{t_0^3}3 \right).
$$

Comment: You could also just use $e^{nx^2}\le 1$ to find that $|x'(t)|\le t^2\implies |x(t)-x(t_0)|\le\frac{|t^3-t_0^3|}3$, which already sufficiently bounds the solution growth.

Comment: I was discussing with other classmates and apparently the solution is defined for all $\mathbb{R}$. Technically since $t_0$ is non defined any $t>t_0$ is also all real numbers.

Comment: @Miquel-Bernat Laporta i Granad For $\mathbb R$, the same reasoning works as for $[0,+\infty)$. It should only be noted that $f(-x)=-f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(x)=-\infty$.